# How to increase the Quota of IndexedDB on Firefox?

Tags: javascript, html, firefox, indexeddb, quota

because I ran into problems using Chrome and IndexedDB for large objects (videos), I've implemented a [test script](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=467886&can=4&colspec=ID%20Pri%20M%20Week%20ReleaseBlock%20Cr%20Status%20Owner%20Summary%20OS%20Modified#hc1) to reproduce the error. When I run this test script on Firefox, I get a "QuotaExceededError" after reaching 2GB of persistent space.

The [developer page](https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/IndexedDB#Storage_limits) on MDN about IndexedDB says, that there should be "no limit on the IndexedDB database's size".

So, is it possible to rise the Quota programmatically (using JavaScript) when this error occurs?
For example, asking the user to store more data.

Thanks,
Kai

Answer (score 1):

The next sentence in the documentation is

> However there may be a limit on each IndexedDB database's size.

So in theory you could add items of infinite size as long as that size is lower than the maximum size of the whole database.

The reason for this limit is to prevent web sites to dump arbitrary amounts of data onto a user's computer. This is a security feature. As far as I know, there is no way to change this size from JavaScript. All browsers limit the the amount of data that a web page can store.

A user can change their preferences (also explained in the documentation) but you will have to explain to them how to do it (for every browser).

Comment: On the MDN page after the first paragraph --> Firefox: no limit on the IndexedDB database's size. What you can edit is the threshold, when the user should be asked if he allows the application to store more data locally. But you cannot increase the database's whole size limit, as far as what I read.

Comment: I feel that part of the documentation is wrong or outdated. Since the appearance of super cookies, I think no browser allows to save any web site to save a lot of data anymore. But I don't know for sure. You may have to ask on the Firefox developer list.

Comment: Can you add a link to the documentation on how a user can change their preferences for indexeddb limits for a site?  I'm having trouble finding it.